# Which is the correct meaning for 保護猫? Protected cat or protecting cat?

Tags: meaning

- 保護**する**猫 protecting cat
- 保護**される**猫 protected cat

But when the bold parts are removed, I don't know the exact meaning.

Which is the correct meaning for 保護猫? Protected cat or protecting cat?

Comment: @JACKB Please try not to answer questions in the comments section.

Answer (score 2):

Based on its usage at animal adoption websites like [this](https://www.veterinary-adoption.com/description/), the word appears to refer to the rescued cat itself, not the people or institution that is doing the rescuing.